# Where can I find a jaxb gradle plugin or custom task that handles a catalog file?

Tags: java, xml, gradle, jaxb

I've tried several and get either

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

...from custom tasks, I guess because the class was removed instead of being deprecated in more recent versions of the JAXB API, or from the jacobono plugin I get...

https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/13

A year old and not yet fixed? :-|

So... is there another way or a work-around or something? I suppose we could re-write our XSD's so that we don't need a catalog file but IDK what other problems that will cause.

Comment: Hmm... my Groovy skills may not be up to the task. :-|

Comment: You might try just using the native Ant tasks provided in Gradle.  I believe I had tried to use that plugin, but gave up on it for other reasons.  I ended up just defining a custom task that calls the Ant.xjc task.

Comment: This is what I've done also. Examples are sparse, but I have one working. Only 2 ba-zillion more to go. ;-)

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Change to the format of an answer and I will give you the cheese. ;-)

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Don't you want the reputation points for the answer?

Comment: I've been busy. I'll get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem quite a while ago trying to integrate JAXB generation with XJC into my build.  I looked at the available XJC plugins (I think I only found one).  However, I found the interface to that plugin was awkward, and it required restructuring my app to fit the restrictions of the plugin.  The author of the plugin didn't think my issue was relevant.

What I finally realized is that the flexibility of Gradle often makes problems like this irrelevant.  I gave up on using that XJC plugin and simply defined my own custom task that directly calls the "ant.xjc" task (Gradle provides all the "native" Ant tasks out of the box).  I put the call to the ant.xjc task into a function that takes a schema file and namespace, and my custom task calls the method several times for each of my XML schemas.

One detail you should note when doing this, particularly with the ant.xjc task, is that you have to be careful what classpath you specify.  With Gradle's ability to define very discrete dependencies, you can specify an "xjc" configuration that only includes the XML jar files that are required by the XJC compiler at runtime.  Those jar files are almost never needed in an application at runtime, so you can avoid deploying those jar files for no reason.

Comment: Spinning up your own plugin probably works great if you are already hot on Groovy but I don't feel like I've even thawed yet. ;-)

Comment: Note that I didn't say here that I wrote my own plugin. I simply wrote a simple custom task that calls a simple Groovy method.  Writing simple Gradle plugins is also pretty simple, but you often don't even need to do that.